# WSL2 127.0.0:4200 with angular ng server working, not with express 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: node.js, wsl2

Recently I installed WSL2 with ubuntu 20.04. I successfully installed nodejs. When I run my angular project with `ng serve` works well. My problem is that a expressjs app runned with `nodemon app.js` can´t be accessed in `127.0.0.1:5000` but in the ip of my VM WSL2.

How can I achive this connection for develop my app?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` *should* work to auto-forward from Windows to WSL, but it sometimes "breaks" when the system is started with "Fast Startup" enabled in Windows or if the system is hibernated.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933) for more detail (short answer -- Try `wsl --shutdown` and see if that helps).  Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455155/11810933) for a caveat on `nodemon` under WSL2.

Comment: Port 5000 may also be in use by a Windows process.

Comment: Finally. `http` server in node need (in wsl2) set a second parameter "0.0.0.0" to permit another equip connect.

Comment: @Legna Interesting.  I would have expected binding to localhost to still work with localhost forwarding.  For instance, when `python3 -m http.server 5000 --bind 127.0.0.1`, I can still access it from Windows via `localhost:5000`.  But if that change worked for you, I do recommend making it a self-accepted answer, at least, to close out the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. `http` server in `nodejs` needs (in wsl2) a second parameter `"0.0.0.0"` to permit another equip connect.